# nifi - consumekafka processor doesn't preserve order - fetched records without any order

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I have simple setup for tests, and during performance tests, I've noticed that nifi read records from kafka in awkward way, it does not preserves order. I have consumekafka_20 procesor connected to logmessage, as on belowed screen
[image]

Both processors are configured to use only one concurent tasks, but log message show messages

```
2021-12-30 17:10:44,612 INFO nifi-0 [Timer-Driven Process Thread-4] o.a.nifi.processors.standard.LogMessage LogMessage[id=0c0931ad-017e-1000-ebfe-53193c54a8b8] caa6dcba-8d44-44be-b7c8-e9ea95481a1c -  - record read from kafka - 71b72dcb-8e31-488c-9fa4-bbeda6494014 - kafka timestamp: 1640884241030 - kafkadebug - offset: 10057 partition: 8
2021-12-30 17:10:47,132 INFO nifi-0 [Timer-Driven Process Thread-4] o.a.nifi.processors.standard.LogMessage LogMessage[id=0c0931ad-017e-1000-ebfe-53193c54a8b8] 90c3cc6f-1142-4aa7-953e-8fa8810877c2 -  - record read from kafka - 71b72dcb-8e31-488c-9fa4-bbeda6494014 - kafka timestamp: 1640884239426 - kafkadebug - offset: 9985 partition: 8
```

As you can see second offset (9985) is far before first one (10057)
Does someone knows why this happens?
`ConsumeKafka_2.0` configuration looks as follows:

[image]

[image]

I was experimentig with `Max poll records` setting but this does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka provides ordering within a partition according to [this cloudera blog post](https://blog.cloudera.com/scalability-of-kafka-messaging-using-consumer-groups/#:%7E:text=Kafka%20does%20not%20guarantee%20ordering,be%20grouped%20by%20during%20processing.)

Try to select `FirstInFirstOutPrioritizer` on the `Queue` between `ConsumeKafka` and `LogMessage`

[image]